# unbind not work in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$("#infoButton").unbind('click');
                $("#infoButton").click(
                    function(event) {
                        try {
                            bla bla bla....
                        } catch (e) {
                            alert(e);
                        }
                    }
                );
```

I found that event have been unbinding all the events, but the "bla bla bla" still accumulating!

The event can not be unbinded.

Jquery version 1.8.2

Comment: Move the unbind below the bind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prevent multiple event binding/triggering

Because of interesting jQM loading architecture, multiple event triggering is a constant problem. For example, take a look at this code snipet:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#index' ,function(e,data){    
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CCfL4/

Each time you visit page **#index** click event will is going to be bound to button **#test-button**. There are few ways to prevent this problem:

**Solution 1:**

> In this case you should use function on instead of bind. It is faster
>   and meant to replace bind and delegate.

Remove event before you bind it:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#index',function(e,data){    
    $(document).off('click', '#test-button').on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K8YmG/

In case you have different events bound to an object:

```
$('#index').on('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $(document).off('click tap', '#test-button').on('click tap', '#test-button',function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

**Solution 2:**

Use a jQuery Filter selector, like this:

```
$('#carousel div:Event(!click)').each(function(){
    //If click is not bind to #carousel div do something
});
```

Because event filter is not a part of official jQuery framework it can be found here:   http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

In a nutshell, if speed is your main concern then **Solution 2** is much better then Solution 1.

**Solution 3:**

A new one, probably an easiest of them all.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        {
            alert('Clicked');
            event.handled = true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Yerv9/

Tnx to the [sholsinger][2] for this solution: http://sholsinger.com/archive/2011/08/prevent-jquery-live-handlers-from-firing-multiple-times/